# Nested dicts inside nested dicts, how to automate them?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to generate a nested dict, inside another nested dict, but I could only get one step done.

Here is the code i got:

```
variables = ['CHG', 'Open', 'Close']
assets= ['GOOG', 'FB']
dates =['28-09-2020', '25-09-2020']

dct = {x: dict(zip(assets, '0' * len(assets))) for x in dates}
```

Gets me:

```
{'28-09-2020': {'GOOG': '0', 'FB': '0'}, '25-09-2020': {'GOOG': '0', 'FB': '0'}}
```

How can i generate the dict, with variables inside each asset?

My objective is to get a dict like this:

```
{'28-09-2020': {'GOOG': {'CHG':0, 'Open':0, 'Close':0}, 'FB': {'CHG':0, 'Open':0, 'Close':0}}, '25-09-2020': {'GOOG': {'CHG':0, 'Open':0, 'Close':0}, 'FB': {'CHG':0, 'Open':0, 'Close':0}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{date: {x: dict(zip(variables, '0' * len(variables))) for x in assets} for date in dates}
```

Output

```
{'28-09-2020': {'GOOG': {'CHG': '0', 'Open': '0', 'Close': '0'},
  'FB': {'CHG': '0', 'Open': '0', 'Close': '0'}},
 '25-09-2020': {'GOOG': {'CHG': '0', 'Open': '0', 'Close': '0'},
  'FB': {'CHG': '0', 'Open': '0', 'Close': '0'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's work this from the inside out.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> dict.fromkeys(variables, 0)
{'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}
>>> dict(zip(assets, repeat(_)))
{'GOOG': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}, 'FB': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}}
>>> dict(zip(dates, repeat(_)))
{'28-09-2020': {'GOOG': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}, 'FB': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}}, '25-09-2020': {'GOOG': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}, 'FB': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}}}
```

So you can use

```
dct = dict(zip(dates, repeat(dict(zip(assets, repeat(dict.fromkeys(variables, 0)))))))
```

or in dict comprehension form

```
dct = {d: {a: dict.fromkeys(variables, 0) for a in assets} for d in dates}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
{d: {a: {v:0 for v in variables} for a in assets} for d in dates}
```

**Output**

```
{'28-09-2020': {'GOOG': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}, 'FB': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}}, 
 '25-09-2020': {'GOOG': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}, 'FB': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NestedDict`. First install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts)

```
pip install ndicts
```

Then

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

variables = ['CHG', 'Open', 'Close']
assets= ['GOOG', 'FB']
dates =['28-09-2020', '25-09-2020']

nd = NestedDict.from_product(dates, assets, variables, value=0)
```

If you need the result as a dictionary

```
>>> nd.to_dict()
    {'28-09-2020': {
        'GOOG': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0},
        'FB': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}},
     '25-09-2020': {
        'GOOG': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0},
        'FB': {'CHG': 0, 'Open': 0, 'Close': 0}}}
```